# How to move cursor to the last blank space in a line in vim?

Tags: vimrc

I understand that to move to the beginning of the line blank space I have to use `0`, but to move to the last blank space in the line '$' or 'end' sign move to the last character. How to move to the last blank space in a line?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I've understood your question correctly. I think you might want to move to the last **non**-whitespace character in the line.

In this case, the built-in `:h g_` does just that (it's the end-of-line counterpart of `_`).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a built in for that, but you can do a search to jump to it`/ [^ ]*$`

This searches for a space, followed by zero or more non-spaces (`[^ ]*`), until the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

If line ends with "space" then <kbd>$</kbd>

Otherwise <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>$</kbd><kbd>F</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>

Comment: You probably didn't understand my question.

Comment: @Audrew I think you should reword your question then, or provide an example. As it stands, I feel like this is an answer to it.